# Eclipse error, Returned exit code=13

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with opening Eclipse Juno 64 bit. Here is a picture of the error:

[image: Eclipse Startup Error]

I don't know why this is happening, and this is my first time seeing an error like this. I have already reinstalled JDK/JRE 64 bit, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try removing the '!' characters from your eclipse executable path.

Comment: Oh my god.
its really work.
T_T
many thanks for helping me. (so piss off with the prob xD)
btw how to make this question Solved?

Answer (score 1):

Config is good, the problem is folder name: remove special character from folders names.

I had a folder named **"Prj#1"** and eclipse show me same error. I had renamed folder as "Prj1" and all works fine.